# Maximum sum of non adjacent numbers in a circular array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I need to find the maximum sum of non continous subsequence, I have the following code.

```java
public int maxSumInSubsequence(int[] data) {  
   if (data == null) return 0;  
   int n = data.length;  

   // maxSum[i] == the maximum sum of subsequences of data[0 .. i] that include data[i]  
   int[] maxSum = new int[n];  
   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
     maxSum[i] = data[i];  
     // maxSum[i-1] includes data[i-1] and thus cannot include data[i]  
     for (int j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {  
       maxSum[i] = Math.max(data[i] + maxSum[j], maxSum[i]);  
     }  
   }  

   // find the max of all subsequences  
   int max = 0;  
   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
     max = Math.max(max, maxSum[i]);  
   }  

   return max;  
 }
```

This works fine, but how do I modify it to exclude the first and the last element from calculation.

Comment: Shouln't the answer be just the sum of all positive elements?

Comment: No .. it has be non continuous sequences , so we cannot just sum up all the array.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "non-continuous".

Comment: For instance , if we have 3, 1, 1, 7 . Then the maximum will be 10 of 3 + 7 and both are non adjacent elements.

Comment: Do you mean a subsequence without any adjacent elements?

Comment: Yes the sum should be consisting of non adjacent elements and not including the first and last.

Comment: OK I don't think "non comtinuous" is exactly the right word here. I would suggest explaining it in the question itself.

Comment: I get the "non continuous" part, but I do not get your question...what do you mean by exclude the first and the last element?

Comment: Since any element can be part of a sum, and that adjacency is transitive, can't you just return Sum(Max(sequence),Max(sequence_excluding_the_max_and_its_adjacents))?

Comment: Emm... Start for-cycles from 1 and use `n=data.length-2`?

Comment: I think you need to provide some more examples of input and outputs. Seems unclear what non-adjacent means, for instance does it mean that once a number is selected, the left and right neighbours cannot be added?

Comment: To avoid including the first and last elements, why not just get rid of them from the array before you start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Iterate over the array to construct another array with starting element as the `i`th element and of length `n-1` that wraps around the array.
2. Execute maxSumInSubsequence over each constructed array and find the resultant maximum.

Also, as mentioned in another answer, `maxSumInSubsequence` could be optimized to have `O(n)` time complexity.

---

```
  public int maxSumInSubsequence(int[] data) {  
    if (data == null) return 0;
    int n = data.length;
    if (n <= 2) return 0;

    // maxSum[i] == the maximum sum of subsequences of data[0 .. i] that include data[i]  
    int[] maxSum = new int[n];  
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
      maxSum[i] = data[i];  
      // maxSum[i-1] includes data[i-1] and thus cannot include data[i]  
      for (int j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {  
        maxSum[i] = Math.max(data[i] + maxSum[j], maxSum[i]);  
      }  
    }  

    // find the max of all subsequences  
    int max = 0;  
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
    max = Math.max(max, maxSum[i]);  
  }

  return max;  
  }

  public int maxCircularSumInSubsequence(int[] data) {
    int n = data.length;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int[] circularData = new int[n-1];
      for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        circularData[j] = data[(i+j) % n];
      }
      max = Math.max(maxSumInSubsequence(circularData), max);
    }
    return max;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Function to return max sum such that no two elements
  are adjacent */
int FindMaxSum(int arr[], int n)
{
  int incl = arr[0];
  int excl = 0;
  int excl_new;
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
     /* current max excluding i */
     excl_new = (incl > excl)? incl: excl;

     /* current max including i */
     incl = excl + arr[i];
     excl = excl_new;
  }

   /* return max of incl and excl */
   return ((incl > excl)? incl : excl);
}
```

Reference : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is to just compute the sum for two possibilities: start *i* from 0 and then sum up with every alternate array no or start *i* with *i* and sum up with every alternate number from there and print the maximum of both.

```
arr=[5,5,10,100,10,50,1]
def max_sum_suchThatNoTwoElements_are_adjacent(arr,n,su,max_sum):

    i=0
    while i<n:
        su+=arr[i]
        if (i+1)<n:
            max_sum+=arr[(i+1)]
        i+=2 


    return max(max_sum,su)  

print(max_sum_suchThatNoTwoElements_are_adjacent(arr,len(arr),0,0))
```